# Share image and text with Intent to Whats App

Tags: android, share

I am trying to share an image from `imageview` with text caption to whatsApp but the solutions I found online didn't seem to work for me.

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.posted_house);
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
        try
        {
            root.createNewFile();
           FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
            ostream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent txtIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        txtIntent .setType("image/*");
        txtIntent .putExtra("message");
        txtIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(cachePath));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(txtIntent ,"Share"));
    }
```

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(root)` – You're trying to create a `FileOutputStream` on `root`. Your image file is `cachePath`, not `root`.

Comment: I edited my code but I get the same result. A black background is shown in the sharing preview

Comment: Is the file being created? Are you getting any logs from the `catch` block? Do you have permission to write to external storage? Are you sure WhatsApp can handle arbitrary files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Here is code for share image and text in whatsapp..

  ```
  View screenView = rootView.getRootView();
  screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
  screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);

  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.setType("image/*");

  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your message");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path));
  try {
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Screenshot"));
  } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "No App Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  ```